# $r<s$ and $L^r\subset L^s$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to proved the following statement:

Let $0<r<s\le\infty$. Then, $L^r(\mu)\subset L^s(\mu)$ if and only if $$ \exists\ \epsilon>0:\forall E\in\mathfrak M,\text{ either } \mu(E)=0\ \text{ or } \mu(E)\ge\epsilon\ . $$
I proved this for $s<\infty$. But, how about the case $s=\infty$?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $L^r\subset L^\infty$. Then $L^r\subset L^{r+1}$, hence from the case $s:=r+1<\infty$, we deduce the existence of the wanted $\varepsilon$.

Conversely, assume that there is some positive $\varepsilon$ such that for each measurable set $E$, $\mu(E)\in \{0\}\cup [\varepsilon,\infty)$. Let $f$ be an element of $L^r$. Define $E_n:=\{f\gt n\}$. Then 
$$n^r\mu(E_n)\leqslant \int_{E_n}|f|^r\mathrm d\mu\leqslant \int |f|^r\mathrm d\mu<\infty,$$
hence $\mu(E_n)\leqslant n^{-r} \int |f|^r\mathrm d\mu$. Take $n$ such that $n^{-r} \int |f|^r\mathrm d\mu\lt \varepsilon$ to obtain $\mu(E_n)=0$, hence $|f(x)|\leqslant n$ for $\mu$-a.e. $x$.